# while i use include layout ,the onclicklistener doesn't work

Tags: android

I want to get imageview from include layout and add a click event, set clickable to be true, but it doesn't work ,somebody tell me  set the focusable to be true , but it still useless .

this is my xml

```
<include layout="@layout/navigation_content"/>
```

next

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeToolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/msBlue"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/homeMenu"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/homeTitle"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/homeMenu"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Home"/>
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/homeShopingCar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:backgroundImage="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_white_24dp"
                app:actualImageScaleType="centerInside"
                />
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/homeSearch"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/homeShopingCar"
                app:backgroundImage="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
                app:actualImageScaleType="center"
                />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

then

```
 View contentView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_content,null);
    homeMenu=(ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.homeMenu);
    homeTitle=(TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.homeTitle);
    homeMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeTitle.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeViewPager.setOnClickListener(this);
```

onClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id=v.getId();
    Log.i("id",id+"");
    switch (id){
        case R.id.homeMenu:
            mainDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            break;
        case R.id.homeTitle:
            mainDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            break;
        case R.id.homeViewPager:
            mainDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

omg i know the reason

```
View contentView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_content,null);
homeMenu=(ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.homeMenu);
homeTitle=(TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.homeTitle);
```

i shouldn't use inflate ,just change to

```
homeMenu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.homeMenu);
homeTitle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.homeTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below syntax should only be used in a fragment situation

```
View contentView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_content,null);
homeMenu=(ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.homeMenu);
homeTitle=(TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.homeTitle);
```

Otherwise you are correct just call as is

```
homeMenu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.homeMenu);
homeTitle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.homeTitle);
```